# Which cloud service I should use for my android app

Tags: android

I would like to allow my users to be able to save data to the cloud. I was wondering, should I use Dropbox so people can hook it up to their account or the cloud service from Parse.com?

Please let me know your thoughts. My user base is around 1000 users, saving probably not more than once a day

Comment: Questions on tools and services get voted down and flagged for deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of data you want to store and what kind of use you want to enable for your users. 
Personally I am not a big fan of Dropbox, but it is a definitely a good solution. I would also look into SkyDrive as it has MS Office built in and it is integrated (or can be integrated with a plugin) in all the major OSes as Dropbox does.